# Replacing particular elements in a list

Tags: python, list

Code:

```
>>> mylist = ['abc','def','ghi']
>>> mylist
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> for i,v in enumerate(mylist):
...     if v=='abc':
...             mylist[i] = 'XXX'
... 
>>> mylist
['XXX', 'def', 'ghi']
>>>
```

Here, I try to replace all the occurrences of `'abc'` with `'XXX'`. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using an explicit for loop, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This allows you to iterate over all the elements in the list and filter them or map them to a new value.

In this case you can use a [conditional expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Python). It is similar to `(v == 'abc') ?  'XXX' : v` in other languages.

Putting it together, you can use this code:

```
mylist = ['XXX' if v == 'abc' else v for v in mylist]
```

Comment: One line answers whilst may be correct, it would be better to include an explanation much like agf has done.

Comment: I was going to but agf had already done so, so I didn't feel it was necessary to do it again. But I will update my answer to include links... Sorry!

Comment: @Kev: There, I think now my answer is even better than agfs. Do you agree?

Comment: Excellent, Mark. This is by far the best outcome of two similar/identical answers being posted.

Comment: In case you didn't see it, it was [my meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/moderator-deletion-of-equivalent-answers) that lead to all this attention.

Comment: @agf: Ah I see. Big, big thanks for saving my answer from the delete moderators! I'll go and find some of your old answers and upvote them. :)

Comment: Hah, thanks. I'm already ahead of the game; my answer got three upvotes since I posted on Meta. More than cancels out you getting the accept :).

Answer (score 11):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a ternary operation / [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
['XXX' if item == 'abc' else item for item in mylist]
```